# cannot connect redis server on ECS

Tags: networking, redis, amazon-ecs

I have php-fpm server and redis server running in containers on ECS. I use laravel in app server. When I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

in php-fpm container, I get the error like

```
In PhpRedisConnector.php line 87:
protocol error, got 'H' as reply type byte
[2023-04-20 13:26:33] testing.ERROR: protocol error, got 'H' as reply type byte
{"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): protocol error, got 'H' as reply type byte
atwork/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:87)
[stacktrace]
#0 /work/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php(87): Redis->auth()
…
```

seems app server cannot connect redis server properly and I believe this is caused by aws network settings.

**Note** This is not my original entire CFN file. I tried to cut unnecessary part to reproduce this problem. DB service, for example. I confirmed the same error occurs with proper db settings to migrate.

My cloudformation templates are as follows.
base-network-template.yaml (run this 1st)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  ClusterName:
    Description: ECS cluster name.
    Type: String
  DesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Number of containers to launch in my ECS cluster.
  MaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Maximum number of containers that can be launched in your ECS cluster.
  MinSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Minimum number of containers that can be launched in your ECS cluster.
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Description: Domain name to access my app.
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 172.16.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  NatGateway1:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatEIP1.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
  NatGateway2:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatEIP2.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
  NatEIP1:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  NatEIP2:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 172.16.0.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: ap-northeast-1a
  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 172.16.1.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: ap-northeast-1c
  PublicSubnet3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 172.16.2.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: ap-northeast-1d
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet3
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 172.16.3.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: ap-northeast-1a
  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 172.16.4.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: ap-northeast-1c
  PrivateSubnet3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 172.16.5.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: ap-northeast-1d
  NatRouteTable1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  NatRouteTable2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  NatRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1
  NatRoute2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable2
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway2
  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable1
  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable2
  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet3
      RouteTableId: !Ref NatRouteTable1

Outputs:
  StackName:
    Description: stack name
    Value: !Ref AWS::StackName
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-StackName"

  VpcId:
    Description: vpc id
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-VpcID"

  PublicSubnet1:
    Description: public subnet 1 ID
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet1ID"

  PublicSubnet2:
    Description: public subnet 2 ID
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet2ID"

  PublicSubnet3:
    Description: public subnet 3 ID
    Value: !Ref PublicSubnet3
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet3ID"
  
  PrivateSubnet1:
    Description: private subnet 1 ID
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnet1ID"

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Description: private subnet 2 ID
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnet2ID"

  PrivateSubnet3:
    Description: private subnet 3 ID
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet3
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnet3ID"
```

main-ecs-stack-template.yaml (run this 2ndly)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  BaseCfnStackName:
    Type: String
    Description: Base cfn template stack name
    MinLength: 1
    MaxLength: 255
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "base-network-template-stack"
  ClusterName:
    Description: ECS cluster name.
    Type: String
    Default: "test"
  DesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Number of containers to launch in your ECS cluster.
  MaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Maximum number of containers that can be launched in your ECS cluster.
  MinSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: '1'
    Description: Minimum number of containers that can be launched in your ECS cluster.
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Description: Domain name to access my app.
    Default: "mydomainname.com"
Resources:
  ECSCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Cluster'
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Ref ClusterName
      ServiceConnectDefaults:
        Namespace: !Ref ClusterName
  ECSLogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - ECSLogGroup
      RetentionInDays: 14
  TaskExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join
        - ''
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - TaskExecutionRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
              - TaskExecutionRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'
                  - 'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability'
                  - 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'
                  - 'ecr:BatchGetImage'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: '*'
        - PolicyName: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
              - GetMySecretPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef'
        - PolicyName: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
              - GetMyEnvFilePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-private-bucket/.env'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetBucketLocation'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::my-private-bucket'
  AppServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join
        - '-'
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - app-server-security-group
      GroupDescription: App Server Security Group
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-VpcID"
  AppServerSecurityGroupOutboundRule1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress'
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref AppServerSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 443
      ToPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  AppServerSecurityGroupOutboundRule3:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress'
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref AppServerSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 6379
      ToPort: 6379
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref KVSSecurityGroup
  AppServerTaskRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join
        - ''
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - AppServerTaskRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId
              ArnLike:
                aws:SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
              - AppServerTaskRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel'
                  - 'ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel'
                  - 'ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel'
                  - 'ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel'
                Resource: '*'
  AppServerTaskDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    DependsOn: ECSLogGroup
    Properties:
      Family: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - app-server
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: app-server
          Cpu: 300
          Memory: 600
          Essential: true
          Image: !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/my_app:latest'
          EntryPoint:
            - 'sh'
            - '-c'
          Command:
            - "composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev --no-scripts --no-plugins && \
              php artisan migrate --force && \ -> I got the error here
              php artisan config:cache && \
              php artisan view:cache && \
              php artisan route cache && \
              php-fpm"
          EnvironmentFiles:
            - Value: "arn:aws:s3:::my-private-bucket/.env"
              Type: "s3"
          Secrets:
            - Name: APP_KEY
              ValueFrom:
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:APP_KEY::"
            - Name: APP_URL
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:APP_URL::"
            - Name: REDIS_PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:REDIS_PASSWORD::"
            - Name: REDIS_PORT
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:REDIS_PORT::"
            - Name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID::"
            - Name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY::"
            - Name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:AWS_DEFAULT_REGION::"
            - Name: AWS_BUCKET
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:AWS_BUCKET::"
            - Name: AWS_PUBLIC_BUCKET
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:AWS_PUBLIC_BUCKET::"
            - Name: ADMIN_EMAIL
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:ADMIN_EMAIL::"
            - Name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:ADMIN_PASSWORD::"
            - Name: LOG_REQUESTS
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:LOG_REQUESTS::"
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref ECSLogGroup
              awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              awslogs-stream-prefix: app-server-service
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 9000
              Name: app-server
              Protocol: tcp
              AppProtocol: http
          LinuxParameters:
            InitProcessEnabled: true
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt AppServerTaskRole.Arn
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt TaskExecutionRole.Arn
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      Cpu: 512
      Memory: 1024
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
  AppServerService:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
    DependsOn:
      - ECSLogGroup
      - KVSService
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredCapacity
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      EnableExecuteCommand: true
      TaskDefinition: !Ref AppServerTaskDefinition
      ServiceName: app-server
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref AppServerSecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - 
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-PrivateSubnet1ID"
            -
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-PrivateSubnet2ID"
            -
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-PrivateSubnet3ID"
      ServiceConnectConfiguration:
        Enabled: true
        Services:
          - PortName: app-server
            DiscoveryName: app-server
            ClientAliases:
              - DnsName: app
                Port: 9000
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: "awslogs"
          Options:
            awslogs-group: !Ref ECSLogGroup
            awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: app-server-service
  KVSSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join
        - '-'
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - kvs-security-group
      GroupDescription: KVS Security Group
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-VpcID"
  KVSSecurityGroupInboundRule1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress'
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref KVSSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 6379
      ToPort: 6379
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref AppServerSecurityGroup
  KVSSecurityGroupOutboundRule1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress'
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref KVSSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 443
      ToPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  KVSTaskRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join
        - ''
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - KVSTaskRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId
              ArnLike:
                aws:SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
              - KVSTaskRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel'
                  - 'ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel'
                  - 'ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel'
                  - 'ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel'
                Resource: '*'
  KVSTaskDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    Properties:
      Family: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - kvs
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: kvs
          Cpu: 250
          Memory: 500
          Essential: true
          Image: !Sub '${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/my_kvs:latest'
          EnvironmentFiles:
            - Value: "arn:aws:s3:::my-private-bucket/.env"
              Type: "s3"
          HealthCheck:
            Command:
              - "CMD-SHELL"
              - "redis-cli ping || exit 1"
          Secrets:
            - Name: REDIS_PASSWORD
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:REDIS_PASSWORD::"
            - Name: REDISCLI_AUTH
              ValueFrom: 
                !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:mysecret-abcdef:REDIS_PASSWORD::"
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref ECSLogGroup
              awslogs-region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
              awslogs-stream-prefix: kvs-service
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 6379
              Name: kvs
              Protocol: tcp
              AppProtocol: http
          LinuxParameters:
            InitProcessEnabled: true
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt KVSTaskRole.Arn
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt TaskExecutionRole.Arn
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      Cpu: 512
      Memory: 1024
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
  KVSService:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
      DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredCapacity
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      EnableExecuteCommand: true
      TaskDefinition: !Ref KVSTaskDefinition
      ServiceName: kvs
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref KVSSecurityGroup
          Subnets:
            - 
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-PrivateSubnet1ID"
            -
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-PrivateSubnet2ID"
            -
              Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${BaseCfnStackName}-PrivateSubnet3ID"
      ServiceConnectConfiguration:
        Enabled: true
        Services:
          - PortName: kvs
            DiscoveryName: kvs
            ClientAliases:
              - DnsName: kvs
                Port: 6379
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: "awslogs"
          Options:
            awslogs-group: !Ref ECSLogGroup
            awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: kvs-service
```

I checked laravel's config/database.php and other redis-related files in app but they seem fine. I am happy to provide it if it is necessary though.

**Edit**
laravel config/database.php is as follows.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'read' => [
                'host' => [
                    env('DB_HOST_READ', 'db'),
                ],
            ],
            'write' => [
                'host' => [
                    env('DB_HOST_WRITE', 'db'),
                ],
            ],
            'sticky' => true,
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            //'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'db'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            //'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/run/mysql/mysql.sock'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
            'timezone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
            'compression' => Redis::COMPRESSION_LZ4,
            'serializer' => Redis::SERIALIZER_MSGPACK,
        ],

        'session' => [
            #'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_SESSION_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            #'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

        'queue' => [
            #'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_QUEUE_DB', '2'),
        ],

        #'broadcast' => [
            #'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        #    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        #    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        #    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        #    'database' => env('REDIS_BROADCAST_DB', '3'),
        #],

    ],

];
```

The following is .env file included in app container.

```
APP_NAME=MYAPP
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_CONNECTION=session
REDIS_HOST=kvs
REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis
REDIS_SESSION_DB=0
REDIS_CACHE_DB=1
REDIS_QUEUE_DB=2
REDIS_QUEUE=default
```

**Edit**
I run `ecs exec` to app container and run `ping` from inside the container. The result was no packet loss. I also run `nc -v kvs 6379` and the result was `kvs [127.255.0.2] 6379 (?) open`. I also installed `redis-cli` cmd in the app container and try to connect to redis server but saw the same error `protocol error, got H as...`. I am going to try to set the easy password to redis to check if some part of the password are not escaped and cause the error.->no luck.

Comment: Where do you have the Redis server hostname or IP address configured in your Laravel app? I'm not seeing that anywhere in your CloudFormation template.

Comment: I added laravel's config/database.php.

Comment: It is using a `REDIS_CLUSTER` environment variable which you aren't setting anywhere, and a `REDIS_HOST` environment variable which you also aren't setting anywhere. Since you aren't setting those, it is defaulting to `127.0.0.1` which is going to resolve to the local php-fpm container, which does not have a Redis service running in it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add .env file. It includes REDIS_HOST which is "kvs".

Comment: I also confirmed these env var are included in containers when entrypoint cmd runs.

Comment: Where is the rest of your Service Discovery configuration? You should be setting a base domain name, like "local.com" for service discovery resolution. The actual DNS name for your Redis server would then be `kvs.local.com` not just `kvs`.

Comment: Sorry I used Service Connect instead of Service Discovery. I think my conf is sufficient but I am not AWS specialist so maybe wrong. In addition, I confirmed　env var from env file inserted and from secrets in container def are both reflected when entrypoint cmd runs.

Comment: I would use `ecs exec` to get back into the PHP container, and run some tests on the command line, such as `ping kvs` or `traceroute kvs` to see if that DNS name is actually resolving to your Redis server's address.

Comment: ok I will try `ecs exec` and check connection tommorrow. Sorry I am in Japan and time for bed. Thx for your advice!

Comment: @MarkB I just tried to ping from app container to kvs container and confirmed no packet loss. I am going to try traceroute from now.

Comment: I didn't get the idea to use traceroute but now I understand. In this case, there is no need to use it, right? Since ping response is ok, this problem is probably not caused by AWS networks.

Comment: @MarkB I also tried netcat command just in case. (I run ```nc -v kvs 6379```) The result was ```kvs [127.255.0.2] 6379 (?) open``` Does this mean connection is ok?

Comment: That sounds like the network connection is working.

Comment: Connect from app container with redis-cli with password but I got the same error. So the problem is likely to be on the redis server side.

Comment: The issue probably solved. The namespace in service connect conf is missing. I am going to try the new conf with it.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I still cannot connect to mysql and redis.

Answer (score 0):

The container is generally not accessible on the internet because it lacks an assigned Elastic Network Interface (ENI), resulting in the absence of a public IP address. To address this issue, you need to establish an internet gateway and ensure that the container connects to the internet through the gateway.